# How to delete assign operator overloding from smart pointer .get()?

Tags: c++, c++11, implementation

I am implementing Smart Pointer, imitating std::shared_ptr

I did most of implementations of its functions.
e.g.) No assign operator from raw pointer. bool operator overloading...

However, in details, shared_ptr allows us by following uses.

--Edit

```
1) shared_ptr<A> pA(new A);  // ok (Let it be Explicit)
2) shared_ptr<A> pA = new A; // no
3) shared_ptr<A> pA = nullptr; // ok (overload with nullptr_t)
4) shared_ptr<A> pA = make_shared<A>(); // usual use
   shared_ptr<A> pA2 = pA.get(); // no
```

It seems .get() returns std::remove_extent_t* in STL lib.
To implement such details, how can I design my SharedPtr functionalities?

Here's my SharedPtr Code might help to understand my question.
(Edited)

```
#pragma once
#include "CriticalSection.h"

template<typename T>
class SharedPtr
{
    template<typename S>
    friend class SharedPtr;
private:
    T*            m_pRes;
    UINT*         m_iRefCount;
    static CriticalSection m_tMutex;

public:
    T* operator->()
    {
        assert(m_pRes && "[SharedPtr] Access Null Obj");
        return m_pRes;
    }
    const T* operator->() const
    {
        assert(m_pRes && "[SharedPtr] Access Null Obj");
        return m_pRes;
    }

    T* Get() { return m_pRes; }
    const T* Get() const { return m_pRes; }
    T** GetAddressOf() { return &m_pRes; }
    T* const* GetAddressOf() const { return &m_pRes; }

    UINT UseCount() const 
    { 
        if (m_iRefCount == nullptr)
            return 0;
        return (*m_iRefCount); 
    }

    void Reset(T* _ptr = nullptr)
    {
        assert(_ptr != m_pRes);

        if (m_pRes)
        {
            SubRef();
        }
        
        m_pRes = _ptr;

        if (m_pRes)
        {
            assert(m_iRefCount == nullptr);
            m_iRefCount = new UINT(1);
        }
    }

    template<typename S>
    SharedPtr<S> CastTo() const
    {
        assert(m_pRes != nullptr && dynamic_cast<S*>(m_pRes) != nullptr);

        SharedPtr<S> pCast;
        pCast.m_iRefCount = m_iRefCount;
        pCast.m_pRes = (S*)m_pRes;
        pCast.AddRef();

        return pCast;
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const { return m_pRes != nullptr; }
    bool operator==(nullptr_t) const { return m_pRes == nullptr; }
    bool operator!=(nullptr_t) const { return m_pRes != nullptr; }
    bool operator==(const SharedPtr<T>& rhs) const { return m_pRes == rhs.m_pRes; }
    bool operator!=(const SharedPtr<T>& rhs) const { return m_pRes != rhs.m_pRes; }

private:
    void AddRef()
    {
        m_tMutex.Lock();
        ++(*m_iRefCount);
        m_tMutex.UnLock();
    }
    void SubRef()
    {
        m_tMutex.Lock();
        --(*m_iRefCount);

        if ((*m_iRefCount) == 0)
        {
            SAFE_DELETE(m_iRefCount);
            SAFE_DELETE(m_pRes);
        }

        m_tMutex.UnLock();
    }
public:
    constexpr SharedPtr() noexcept
        :
        m_pRes(nullptr),
        m_iRefCount(nullptr)
    {}
    constexpr SharedPtr(nullptr_t) noexcept
        :
        m_pRes(nullptr),
        m_iRefCount(nullptr)
    {}
    explicit SharedPtr(T* _ptr)
        :
        m_pRes(_ptr),
        m_iRefCount(nullptr)
    {
        if (m_pRes)
        {
            m_iRefCount = new UINT(1);
        }
    }
    ~SharedPtr()
    {
        if (m_pRes)
        {
            SubRef();
        }
    }
    SharedPtr& operator=(nullptr_t)
    {
        if (m_pRes)
        {
            SubRef();
        }

        m_pRes = nullptr;
        m_iRefCount = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    SharedPtr(const SharedPtr<T>& rhs)
        :
        m_pRes(rhs.m_pRes),
        m_iRefCount(rhs.m_iRefCount)
    {
        if (m_pRes)
        {
            AddRef();
        }
    }
    SharedPtr& operator=(const SharedPtr<T>& _ptr)
    {
        if (m_pRes)
        {
            SubRef();
        }

        m_pRes = _ptr.m_pRes;
        m_iRefCount = _ptr.m_iRefCount;

        if (m_pRes)
        {
            AddRef();
        }

        return *this;
    }
    SharedPtr(SharedPtr<T>&& rhs) noexcept
        :
        m_pRes(rhs.m_pRes),
        m_iRefCount(rhs.m_iRefCount)
    {
        rhs.m_pRes = nullptr;
        rhs.m_iRefCount = nullptr;
    }
    SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr<T>&& _ptr) noexcept
    {
        if (m_pRes)
        {
            SubRef();
        }

        m_pRes = _ptr.m_pRes;
        m_iRefCount = _ptr.m_iRefCount;

        _ptr.m_iRefCount = nullptr;
        _ptr.m_pRes = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename T>
CriticalSection SharedPtr<T>::m_tMutex = {};
```

Comment: Your example for `(2)` [does not compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/beaonKxxE), and nor should it since [the `shared_ptr(Y* p)` constructor is `explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Comment: `shared_ptr<A> pA = new A;` doesn't compile.  `shared_ptr<A> pA2 = pA.get();` doesn't compile for the exact same reason. Similarly, `shared_ptr<A> pA2(pA.get());` does compile, for the same reason `shared_ptr<A> pA(new A);` compiles. You are trying to ascribe some magic properties to `shared_ptr::get` - it doesn't possess any.

Comment: Thanks !, I misunderstood shared_ptr in overloading. Looked into STL implementation shared_ptr and appreciated for your explain;

Comment: You are not using  the critical section correctly.

Comment: Lock(), UnLock() are using EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection As a class member function. Could you give me any suggestions?